# Create form for Users on one page and then display lisy of Users on another using Angular

Tags: angular, forms

I have two pages, one for creating user form and another for showing list of users. On first page when i fill in the details (firstname, lastname, username, email, phone, address, salary) when i click on button submit the new user is saved. And when I go to User page, it is shown in the list of Users.

My question is, how can I do that? Is it a basic form or no?
Please, im new to Angular8

Comment: I recommend going through the heros tour angular tutorial. This is covered.

Comment: Thanks for the answer! I just went there and found what I needed.